# What is wrong with this function that intends to calculate number of holidays between two dates?

Tags: oracle, function, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-function

I am new to creating Oracle functions. What is wrong with this function?

```
create or replace
FUNCTION count_holidays(
      t_date DATE,
      p_date DATE)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    return_dt NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dated)
    FROM holiday_new
    WHERE TRUNC(dated)     IN
      (SELECT TRUNC(t_date) + level - 1 
      from dual
        CONNECT BY level <= TRUNC(p_date)-TRUNC(t_date) + 1
      )
    INTO return_dt
    FROM dual;
    RETURN return_dt;
  END;
```

**Error:**

*Error(9,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(16,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended*

Answer (score 4):

This query is wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dated)
FROM holiday_new
WHERE TRUNC(dated) IN
  (    SELECT TRUNC(t_date) + level - 1 
       from dual
       CONNECT BY level <= TRUNC(p_date)-TRUNC(t_date) + 1
  )
INTO return_dt
FROM dual;
```

Proper syntax is:

```
SELECT expression-list INTO variable-list
FROM table .... etc
```

I guess that this query should look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dated) INTO return_dt
FROM holiday_new
WHERE TRUNC(dated) IN
  (    SELECT TRUNC(t_date) + level - 1 
       from dual
       CONNECT BY level <= TRUNC(p_date)-TRUNC(t_date) + 1
  );
```

---

This is very inefficient way to select records with some dates, I would use this query istead:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dated) INTO return_dt
FROM holiday_new
WHERE dated >= trunc(t_date) AND dated < trunc(p_date + 1);
```